# RegEx extract values from string using C#

Tags: c#, regex

Given the following string:

"[##-##] random stuff but nothing like the first pattern of the brackets and digits"

Where ## is basically a random number of digits, what regular expression and coding method could be used to reliably extract the first ## and the second ## using C#?

---

SOLUTION: From answer below (slightly modified):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]");
if (match.Success) {
    //match.Groups[0].Value is the first number
    //match.Groups[1].Value is the second number
}
```

Comment: `\[(\d{2})-(\d{2})\]` ?

Comment: close, use `\d+` instead of `\d{2}`.  He said random number, not "exactly 2"......`+` indicates "one or more".  Also, I think the `-` needs to be escaped as well.

Comment: @Nevyn you could at least let him search of the meaning and "fix" it to his needs :p

Comment: There's a reason I would make a bad teacher.  I have trouble only giving a partial answer to a question and telling the person to go look it up....even if that's how I do things myself.

Comment: Let's get into psychological thoughts, why did he use `##` instead of `#` ?

Comment: It might be one, might be two digits, might be three, or whatever in the ## example provided. RegEx is challenging to me though, thus my question.

Comment: @lantram What about 33.222 ?

Comment: Okay, ## in the example represents only round integers. :)

Comment: Is 0 a possibility for your "random number of digits"? Meaning is "[-122] blah blah blah" still valid? Also could "[12-34] random text [1337-007] blah" happen?

Comment: @lantram In the programming world, you have to be precise :)

Comment: And is `[##-##]` guaranteed to be the start of the string/ is required to be the start?

Comment: It is guaranteed to be the start of the string. For example: "[0-0] foo", "[100-3] bar". Sorry I wasn't more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"\[(\d+)-(\d+)\]");
if (match.Success) {
    //match.Groups[1].Value is the first number
}
```

Comment: I believe this is correct, except the index is off. See edit to my original message above. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `Groups[0]` gives you the matching string, e.g `[##-##]` indexes `1` and `2` would give you the captured numbers. Also you might want to anchor the regex at the beginning of the string - would be more efficient and it would work if you have the same type of string elsewhere in the string (which you say you won't).